# Как подогнать высоту div'a под высоту изображения?

Tags: css

Как сделать, чтобы div.c-a-right по высоте был равен изображению? Высота изображения динамически изменяется. Необходимо, чтобы соседний div всегда был той же высоты, что и изображение.

```
  <article class='c-article'>
       <img src='images/01_01.jpg'>
       <div class='c-a-right'>
        <h5>Заголовок</h5>
        <div class='c-a-text'>
         <p>Текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст</p>
         <p>Текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст</p>
         <p>Текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст</p>
        </div>
        <div class='c-a-link'><a href='#'>Подробнее></a></div>
       </div>
      </article>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div.c-a-right').css('height', $('img').height());
```

Comment: Так то, конечно можно. Но хочется на чистом CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Проще некуда:

```
.c-article {
    display: table;
}
.c-article > * {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

**[Посмотреть пример](http://jsfiddle.net/PF6dH/)**